# How to reduce all the fields of object in java

Tags: java, reduce

I have a Pojo class with all numeric fields

```
public class Pojo {
    private long field1;
    private long field2;
    private long field3;
    private long field4;
    private long field5;
    private double field6;
    private double field7;
    private double field8;
    private double field9;
}
```

And there is a list of Pojo, I want map this list to one Pojo object which will contain in its field the of pojos foe, list. I mean someething like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Pojo> pojoList = getPogoList();
    Pojo pojoInSum = reduceAllFields(pojoList);
}
```

What is the simplest way to reduce all fields of pojos from list without reflection?

Comment: You could use reflection, but consider refactoring the way you do stuff. What do you need this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Stream#reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method:

```
public void reducePojoList() {
    PojoReduce pojoReduce = new PojoReduce();

    List<Pojo> pojoList = Arrays.asList(
            new Pojo(3L, 4.0),
            new Pojo(6L, 1.1));

    Optional<Pojo> reducedPojo = pojoList.stream().reduce(this::combine);

    reducedPojo.ifPresent(System.out::println);
}

private Pojo combine(Pojo pojo1, Pojo pojo2) {
    return new Pojo(
            pojo1.getLongField() + pojo2.getLongField(),
            pojo1.getDoubleField() + pojo2.getDoubleField()
    );
}
```

You would have to update the `combine` method for every field you add though. You'd also be creating a lot of new objects.

Answer (score 1):

The **simplest** way is to write a method in that pojo. Because if you are modeling a thing in a class you should expose behavior and not data.

But I doubt that is what you are looking for so you might want to look at reflection.
Basically you retrieve all the fields of a class, get the values for the instance and then sum them in a loop or stream.

Comment: Having that explicit method is still a very good approach. There might be even a chance to simply have your IDE generate such a method.